# Losing Internet Connection When Connecting To VPN

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, sstp

So whenever I connect either my Windows 7 computer, or Windows Server 2008 R2 server to an SSTP VPN running on a Windows Server 2008 R2 box, I lose internet connection. One suggestion I got was, on the client side, open the VPN properties, go to Networking, IPv4, Advanced, DNS tab, and uncheck "Register this connection's address in DNS". But even with doing that, I still don't have much of an internet connection to browse the web or ping a website such as Google.

Any idea what I can do to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you routing all the traffic in the tunnel? That could be your problem.

[This could solve your problem...](https://superuser.com/questions/12022/how-can-i-make-the-windows-vpn-route-selective-traffic-by-destination-network)

The answer that was accepted seemed a plausible solution to what you are describing.

*You can turn off taking over your entire connection by going to the properties of the VPN, Networking tab, "Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)" properties, Advanced, untick "Use default gateway on remote network". This may or may not leave a route to 192.168.123.0/24 depending on the VPN server's setup. If it doesn't, you'll have to manually add the route each time, although you could put it in a batch file.*

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is so trivial, though I had to go through dozens of pages to find this one.

Answer (score 0):

After connecting to VPN, check IPV6 is checked in network properties(windows+R and type ncpa.cpl). If so, uncheck and try.
[uncheck IPV6 option as described](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blKVV.png)