# Access the internet from within VPN

Tags: vpn

I have a computer witch is connected to a VPN. The VPN has no internet access.

How can I still be connected to the VPN but use my internet connection?

Do I need to use 2 network cards ?

Some simple explanation on how this can be acomplished is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: What operating system is your machine running.  It's an easy fix in Unix/Linux and MAY be an easy fix in Windows.

Comment: Are you the administrator of the VPN?  Can you actually provide some details to your question, since there is a bajillion different different types of VPNs?  Anyway, the answer to this is, `setup your routes correctly`.

Comment: @Everett my machine is running windows 7

Comment: And what VPN software (Cisco, OpenVPN, built in, what)???

Comment: Based on the accumulated comments you've left out a number of key points. Please edit this question so that it includes a complete description of what you're trying to accomplish and can be answered without us playing 20-questions in the comments. See [this meta question](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault) for some tips on what goes into asking a good, answerable question.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are not using a [split tunnel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling) that means all traffic you are generating is going in the VPN tunnel.

[Here is a similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/261003/losing-internet-connection-when-connecting-to-vpn/261009#261009) I had answered a looong time ago...but within this galaxy.

Comment: It's not that easy I want to run a tcp server on my machine that will have a public ip address but still access the server that is on the vpn.

Answer (score 0):

In OS X make sure "Send all traffic over VPN connection" is not checked.

[image]

Comment: What does OSX have to do with this question?

Comment: I'm trying to demonstrate that leaving out a critical piece of information (like what operating system is being used) gets you any convenient answer.  Show me where he says he's NOT using OS X, or any other OS for that matter...